# How can I use mysql table as a unique key generator in Spring Boot JPA?

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I want to generate unique keys at run time across regions and the key generation will be owned by master region. I will have one table with one column(key) with default value as 0 and one row only. Now whenever I need to generate the new unique key,i will increment that column key and return its value. Now I want both this to happen in a transactional way: Increment count of column and return value.My  method will look as:

int generateKey(){

1. UPDATE key_generation SET key = key+1;
2. Select * from key_generation limit 1;
   }

How can I ensure that both of this are executed together and no read/write should happen on this table when this one request is running?

Comment: MySQL has auto_increment columns. Would this work for you?

Comment: yeah.but how can i make sure that multiple requests should not get same value? Insert and then select should run as a one serial code.

Comment: That's exactly what the auto_increment does.

Answer (score 0):

You should use auto_increment for that purpose.

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: but let us say two request comes to server, and since both requests,say a and b, will do db write. and if a does write and it inserted a value and the id now contains 1, how do I make sure that I read the value 1 before the second request to insert id=2 comes,?what id second request comes and it inserts 2 and then the read of first request comes.I am more interested in making insert+select as one serial block in spring.How can I do that

Comment: That's how transaction work. You don't have to do anything